# Print first word of the output

Tags: awk, apt, head

I've been looking around and haven't found what I'm trying.
I have to say I'm petty poor with grep, sed and awk though.

I have an alias:

```
alias upgradable='apt list --upgradable'
```

and it gets me what I need:

```
thunderbird/bionic-updates,bionic-security 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
thunderbird-gnome-support/bionic-updates,bionic-security 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:68.2.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
```

however I'd like to get only the first word, the header of it.
Tried lots of stuff but all failed.

How do I have to proceed ?

Comment: First "word" would be `thunderbird` is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that'd work ! However your question made me realise I'd like to have printed anything before the first /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print everything before the first `/` you can use `cut`:

```
alias upgradable='apt list --upgradable | cut -d'/' -f1
```

or `awk`:

```
alias upgradable="apt list --upgradable | awk -F'/' '{print \$1}'"
```

Comment: Doh thanks @steeldriver

Comment: That's it. Seems so easy and obvious when you say it. Really gotta learn me some awk.
Cheers !

Comment: @Torof: `cut` will be faster than awk however for something like this probably trivially so.

Answer (score 0):

Any regex will d.

`alias upgradable='apt list --upgradable | perl -pe "s|\s.*||" '`

your output:
`thunderbird/bionic-updates,bionic-security`

or 
`alias upgradable='apt list --upgradable | perl -pe "s|/.*||" '`

your output:
`thunderbird`

`perl -pe` will treat everything like one line, and '\n' as regular character. This way it will discard everything behind first white character (1'st example) or behind '/' (2'nd example), inlcudind those separators.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `grep`:

```
apt list --upgradable | grep  -o "^.*\/" | cut -d'/' -f1
```

I don't know how it compares for speed with `awk` or `sed`.